# How to restart on Dagger 2 a dependency of Retrofits 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2

I'm using dagger 2 and retrofit2 in a project that can change the country configurations and also the URL of the country you are pointing at for requesting data.

**Is there any way Dagger2 can create again a Retrofit instance which will include the new URL?**

So the idea is to restart the dependency of Retrofif whenever the user changes its country.

Comment: shouldn't the country be a parameter to your requests?

Comment: I wish but for each country we are using a different URL.

Comment: I would use a wrapper around the retrofit adapter that would provide a retrofit adapter matching the correct country, keeping the last instance used.

Comment: So, in this case, should I have retrofit as @_Provider @_Singleton ?

Comment: probably not retrofit directly, possibly a container class that would check the country each time

Comment: The user will probably *not* change his country more than once per second. Probably not event more than once per minute. Creating a new component with a module supplying the country information to it whenever he does so is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally a solution that works. However I am not 100% sure about its performance cost.

Knowing that a user won't change the country too often or perhaps only once after installing the app, we can call again to **DaggerAppComponent.builder().... .build()** in the *Custom Application* class or whenever it is defined in a project. So once it instantiates again retrofit It will take the new URL.

As I said, this may have a cost of performance but this won't happen too often.